# cocos2dx(2.0.4) android create project issue

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I have download cocos2dx 2.0.4(2012-11-02) and create project by running bat file for Android,, but there is no files generate inside the src\org\cocos2dx?
I have issue with version 2.0.3 also.
Can anyone help to resolve the issue.

```
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/18007?r=18048#message-18048
```

OS: Windows 7(32 bit)
Platform : Android

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They build the cocos2d-x java code separately. You need to create android project using existing source (same as when you do it for your project in eclipse) using the platform/android/java folder , then add this project as a library project of your own project.

Comment: thanks dude, i hv create project and add package into my project from platform/android/java

Answer (score 0):

Edit the batch file called create-android-project.bat to adapt it to your environment, something like:
set _CYGBIN=C:\cygwin\bin
The path of cygwin bin

set _ANDROIDTOOLS=D:\android\android-sdk-windows\tools
The path of android sdk tools

set _NDKROOT=D:\android\android-ndk-r7b
The root of ndk

Please feel free to ask if any issue

"Helping Other means helping yourself"